# PostMan Pre-Request Script: How Do I Get All Iteration Data In A Single Iteration As An Object?

Tags: javascript, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

I am familiar with the syntax to retrieve a single value from a data file in single iteration (shown below), but is there a quick way to retrieve all iteration data within a single iteration as an object?   Or do I need to do this the long way by retrieving each value from the data file individually and adding it to an object?

***Example of retrieving a single value:***

```js
var my_data = pm.iteradtionData.get("variable_name");
```

***I've Attempted The Following, But These Do Not Work:***

```js
var my_data = pm.iteradtionData.JSON();
```

and

```js
var my_data = pm.iteradtionData.get();
```

Googling this hasn't seemed to return anything useful

Answer (score 1):

```js
var my_data = pm.iterationData.toObject();
```

Source: [Postman JavaScript reference](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/postman-sandbox-api-reference/)